# error() function from Stroustrup's book behavior in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++

So I've arrived at Chapter 5 exercises in Programming Principles and Practices Using C++

I'm using VS 2015 as my IDE and I encountered a problem with errors.

If I run the code in Visual Studio 2015 and enter -280 to check the temp I get this: [image: Visual studio error]

However, if I run the same code in codeblocks I get this: [image: Codeblocks error]

As you can see, error given from codeblocks actually writes out the error message while VS 2015 does not. I tried to find out why this is happening but without success so far.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

double ctok(double c)   //converts c to k
{

    if (c<-273.15) error("Temperature below absolute zero!"); // checks that temp isn't below absolute zero
    double k = c + 273.15;
    return k;
}

double ktoc(double k)
{
    double c = k - 273.15;
    return c;
}

int main() {

    double c = 0;       //declare input variable
    cin >> c;           //input temp
    double k = ctok(c); //convert temp
    cout << k << '\n';      //print out tmep

    return 0;
}
```

I'd be thankful if anyone would be able to explain the difference between the two. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where is `error()` defined?

Comment: In the header file std_lib_facilities.h which I have included. Here is the direct link to the header file: http://stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h

Comment: Can you edit the question and add that?

Comment: test1.cpp: In function ‘double ctok(double)’:
test1.cpp:8:60: error: ‘error’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/79591/

Comment: it's maybe your error function issues this error. use the debugger

Comment: Hit that debug button, my friend. That sucker will make your life as a programmer an order of magnitude easier. The debugger is built to help you find and solve bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `error()` function throws `std::runtime_error` exception that is not handled anywhere. When the exception is not handled, `terminate()` is called. `terminate()` calls `std::terminate_handler()` which calls `abort()`.

It looks like `terminate_handler()` from standard library shipped with CodeBlocks behaves differenlty - it prints the type of the exception that caused `terminate()` and it's `std::exception::what()` to the console. Visual Studio's `std::terminate_handler()` implementation doesn't do that, but it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

When an exception is not caught in the program, it is terminated abnormally. Different run time environments treat that differently. The standard does not guarantee any uniform mechanism that we can rely on.

There is nothing you can do about that other than learn how to deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recompile your code using Bjarne Stroustrop's std_lib_facilities.h (http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

using namespace std;

double ctok(double c)   //converts c to k
{

    if (c<-273.15) {
        error("Temperature below absolute zero!"); // checks that temp isn't below absolute zero
        return 0;
    }
    double k = c + 273.15;
    return k;
}

double ktoc(double k)
{
    double c = k - 273.15;
    return c;
}

int main() {

    double c = 0;       //declare input variable
    cin >> c;           //input temp
    double k = ctok(c); //convert temp
    cout << k << '\n';      //print out tmep

    return 0;
}
```

And this message comes out

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/hash_map:60:0,
                 from std_lib_facilities.h:34,
                 from test1.cpp:3: /usr/include/c++/4.9/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning:
#warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use
-Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]  #warning \   ^
```

everything else looks fine after executing the code, and entering the value of the temperature to be -300

```
suhubdyd@paris:~/Documents/code/testcpp$ ./test1 
-300
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Temperature below absolute zero!
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I apologize, but I used Linux Debian to compare. I guess there is something wrong with Windows?

Comment: I don't know, I assume it's Visual Studio related. As you can see codeblocks seems to give a 'correct' version where it actually writes out the error message (what():  Temperature below absolute zero!)

Comment: @Bayaz Visual Studio running a debug build will stop dead when an uncaught exception is thrown so that you may hit the debug button and use the debugger to find out what went wrong with the program. An uncaught exception almost always means something bad happened and Visual Studio is trying to give you a leg up on finding out what.